# Validate Ruby Syntax using Ruby

Tags: ruby, validation, syntax

I need to validate that a given string is valid Ruby syntax, programmatically, using Ruby.  I imagine one way I can do this is by running the code in an EVAL statement, and detecting syntax errors that way.

What's a more proper, safer way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Instead of running the code with EVAL, perhaps just run `ruby -c`?

Comment: I need to do this programmatically in the controller action that receives the form submission, and I'd prefer not to use programmatically access the filesystem or command line to do so, unless I'm misunderstanding.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: This sounds **extremely dangerous**. Is there any way to do this other than by posting and running raw Ruby code? What's the actual objective here? There's really no "safe" way to run arbitrary code. Shopify has made an effort to contain [Ruby in a sandbox](https://github.com/Shopify/mruby-engine) so you may want to consider that approach.

Comment: Definitely, executing the code, as in an eval, would be extremely dangerous, which is why I'd rather a different solution.  The goal here is to _ensure a string has valid ruby syntax_, **without** executing any arbitrary code.

Comment: I don't know of a Ruby parser that prevents execution, though you might be able to staple something on the beginning of the code that prevents it from actually doing anything when it's evaluated. For example, `exit(0)`.

Comment: That's a clever solution, though not ideal, it beats writing my own Ruby parser for this.

Comment: @tadman I don't think so. I don't think it is dangerous at all.

Comment: @choey Why do you expect Ruby on Rails to do this? Isn't this a purely Ruby matter?

Comment: @sawa You're probably right, it's purely a Ruby matter.  I had only mentioned Ruby on Rails since the code I'm looking to syntax check is Ruby on Rails.  I wasn't sure if perhaps there were slight differences In Rails compared to vanilla Ruby.

Comment: @sawa `eval` is how you get remote code execution bugs, which are honestly the absolute worst kind to have.

Comment: @tadman How is `eval` relevant?

Comment: @choey Since Ruby on Rails is just libraries on top of Ruby, a valid Ruby on Rails code must be a valid Ruby code.

Comment: @sawa Numerous critical, business destroying bugs have been introduced over the years into Ruby packages and at the very end of that trail of destruction is a well intended, but poorly protected `eval`.

Comment: @sawa thank you for clarifying this - I'll remove the rails references from the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the code string be `code`. The standard way is to do something like this:

```
begin
  RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile(code)
  nil
rescue Exception => e
  ... # Put code here to return `e` itself, print its message, or whatever you like
end
```

If an error is raised and is rescued, that error will display the syntax error. If not (and `nil` is returned), then `code` is syntactically valid Ruby code (which does not guarantee that it is free of other types of errors).

The comments saying it is dangerous to do, etc, does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Beautiful - this is exactly what I was looking for.  I had previously stated in the question that this code string is coming from the front-end via a ruby editor and ajax, which I later removed to simplify the question, but that is probably why there are comments saying the eval approach is dangerous.  I didn't want to be executing arbitrary code coming from the internet, so this solution is much better.

Comment: Using `eval` may be dangerous, but the  comments that I mentioned are those that do not mention `eval` but say that doing this is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider checking this in the browser with Opal - https://github.com/opal/opal

Comment: This is very cool, and I may use it for checking the syntax on the front-end, but I'm mainly looking for a back-end solution.